# Lenovo P50 Workstation w/ Thinkpad Workstation Doc

Tags: sound, lenovo, thinkpad

I have Ubuntu 14.04.03 working on my new Lenovo P50. There is one issue. Audio will not play out of the audio jack on the back of the docking station.

lspci -nn | grep Audio shows:

00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a170] (rev 31)

I've tried modifying in /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf and adding these different options:

options snd-hda-intel model=thinkpad

and then I tried

options snd-hda-intel model=lenovo-dock

None of them worked. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Could you please try again with 15.10 or at least the HWE wily kernel?  If you haven't already https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingSoundProblems is worth a read.

Comment: Was this audio issue eventually resolved? Considering a P50.

Comment: Not yet. I reverted it back to Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem (same laptop, same Ubuntu version).
I solved it following instructions from a website I dont remember anymore.
According to my last shell commands, I did the following:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-audio-dev/alsa-daily 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install oem-audio-hda-daily-lts-vivid-dkms
```

The following was added to my `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` (don't know if its needed):

```
options snd-hda-intel probe_mask=1 model=auto 
options snd-hda-intel model=pch position_fix=1
```

Comment: This didn't work. I'm wondering if the port on the docking station is bad or not. I guess I can install Windows to find out.

Comment: Looks like the port is fine, this is definitely an issue with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

It's still valid - it's October, I have Ubuntu 14.04.5 (with the xenial kernel), and the exact same problem as Byron - tho my output lists like:

```
wjl@wjl-tp50:~$ lspci -nn | grep Audio
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio [8086:a170] (rev 31)
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:0fbc] (rev a1)
```

Got the sound working without the docking station (also via HDMI), but not when the machine is docked.

And, unlike Byron, it also doesn't work with Windows 10. When I boot that up, the headphone jack on the back of the docking station is completely ignored, and the HDMI output(s) shown as 'inactive'.

Since I've tried that, I also don't have sound on the notebook's jack anymore, tho it is still recognized (hotpluggable) in Ubuntu.

Update: have to correct myself; it's working under W10 - so I'll open a bug in 'audio' for this...

Update: done; please see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1630860